# How to transform part of the text into active element?

Tags: swift, regex, swiftui, nlp

There's a feature in apple notes that highlights the dates from the text after the user finished typing [see on the picture] and allows to appoint event in the calendar.
There's the same function in Whatsapp messenger.

What can be the pseudocode for this?

How is this feature done? I want to do something similar, but I want to choose thematic things from the text and do actions on them. For example, if the text is about animals, all the animals should be highlighted, and action on this element can be done.

[image]

I thought that it may be done with `Regex pattern` or `str. contains("...")`?

The question is what to do when I find the word? To slice the string into 3 parts, so that the middle is somehow transformed into a button with the underlined label? Hot to compound it all together after slicing, as well, how to perform the slice itself?

```
var str = "Let's go tomorrow at 18:00 to walk with my monkey. 
           We can also go to the coffeeshop."
    let animals = ["chicken", "crocodile", "cow", "bear", "goose", "monkey", "dog"]
    for animal in animals {
        if str.contains(animal) {
            print(animal)
            // transform that part of the text into button with underlined label
        }
    }
```

Here's an example when applied in actual interface

`// Notice! If I write in TextEditor "Let's meet tomorrow at 18:00", the date in Text() view won't be highlighted`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var str = "This is some editable text..."
    @State private var tapped = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(str)
                    .padding(40)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            
            TextEditor(text: $str)
                .padding(40)
                .border(Color(UIColor.separator))
                .onTapGesture {
                    tapped += 1
                    if tapped == 1 {
                        str = ""
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here's the `Regex` approach, as I guess it's what was done with the date. It's not ready (very raw), but only the direction.

```
func stringDeduction(of inputText: String) {
    
    // some regex pattern here
    let pattern = "at [0-9]{1,}"
    let regexOptions: NSRegularExpression.Options = [.caseInsensitive]
    let matchingOptions: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [.reportCompletion]
    
    // TODO - catch errors with regex
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: regexOptions)
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: inputText.utf8.count)


    if regex.firstMatch(in: inputText, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: inputText.utf8.count)) != nil {
        print("*: Match!")
    } else {
        print("*: No match.")
    }



    func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
            let results = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
            
            return results.map {
                String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
            }
            
        } catch {
            print("invalid regex")
            return []
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without access to their source code I don't know how Apple or Whatsapp achieve this - but with your simple example text it could easily be done with a regular expression:

```
(?:\w+\s+at\s+)?\d{1,2}:\d{2}
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/KR1Mmt/1

*If you find further examples that require more than this please post a comment here and I'll see if it can be updated.*

Comment: Hi Steve! Thanks. Maybe you have an idea how the initial string gets cut? When the word(s) in text are found, their position also should be found; the string sliced, and each part is assigned to a new variable (3 overall) `beginning` `foundPhrase` `remainingSentence`.
I don't know how to find the position when I found the word. And how to make the slice.

Comment: I haven't used Swift before but the suggested regular expression captures the whole text (rather than say having individual groups) so think it ought to be simple enough via the `range` property of [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression). (If not please post again and I'll have a go at coding it up).